# WPF: What is the DataGrid's version of TextSearch.TextPath?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to use type-down in data grids. With combo boxes this is just the TextSearch.TextPath property.

What property/code would I need for data grid?

Answer (score 0):

I asked about TextSearch in DataGrid in the MSDN forum and the answer was that DataGrid does not implement this functionality.

[MSDN forum discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a73b2cdc-460e-47b6-af97-bdca154fa298/#5abdf41a-03bf-4cc2-a163-3077c5117b0b)